# Multiple query on DBpedia endpoint for movie information retrieval using Apache Jena

Tags: java, jena, semantic-web, dbpedia

I'm trying to download some films' information(year of production and title) using Apache Jena and querying the DBpedia public endpoint.
I already know that the public endpoint has some security restrictions and for this reason it doesn't grant to use query which return more than 2000 rows in the results set.
For this reason, I've tried to subdivide my query in multiple query using the LIMIT and OFFSET option appropriately and with a Java program (http://ideone.com/xF0GCE) I'll save them on a specific file in a formatted manner:

```
public void movieQuery(String dbpediaFilms) throws IOException {
     String includeNamespaces = "PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>\n" +
      "PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>\n" +
      "PREFIX dcterms: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>\n" +
      "PREFIX dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>\n";

       String currQuery = includeNamespaces + "SELECT DISTINCT ?movie (str(?movie_title) as ?title) (str(?movie_year) as ?year) WHERE {\n" +
       " ?movie rdf:type dbpedia-owl:Film.\n" +
       " ?movie rdfs:label ?movie_title.\n" +
" ?movie dcterms:subject ?cat .\n" +
" ?cat rdfs:label ?movie_year .\n" +
" FILTER langMatches(lang(?movie_title), \"EN\") .\n" +
" FILTER regex(?movie_year, \"^[0-9]{4} \", \"i\")\n" +
" } limit 2000 offset ";
      int totalNumberOfFilms = 77794;
      int totNumQuery = 39;
      int offset = 0;
      int currNum = 0;

      for(int i = 1; i <= totNumQuery; i++) {
      try {

         Query query = QueryFactory.create(currQuery + offset);
         currNum += Utils.serializeMappingList(getMovieMappingList(query), dbpediaFilms);

       } catch (Exception ex) {
             ex.printStackTrace();
             throw ex;
        }

      offset += 2000;

      myWait(30);

     }

     System.out.println(currNum);


}
```

This is the query that I use in order to retrieve the information that I need:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?movie (str(?movie_title) as ?title) (str(?movie_year) as ?year) WHERE    { ?movie rdf:type dbpedia-owl:Film.
  ?movie rdfs:label ?movie_title.
  ?movie dcterms:subject ?cat .
  ?cat rdfs:label ?movie_year .
  FILTER langMatches(lang(?movie_title), "EN") .
  FILTER regex(?movie_year, "^[0-9]{4} ", "i")
  } limit 2000 offset $specific_offset
```

As you can see in the java code, I increments a variable (offset) by 2000 in order to acquire the correct results set partition.

Running a preliminar query, I've seen that the total number of distinct films in DBpedia is 77794 using this query:

```
select distinct count(?film) where {
?film rdf:type dbpedia-owl:Film.
}
```

The problem  is that if I count the number of obtained nodes, is equal to 76000 so I think that I've missed a lot of films using this procedure.
Someone can say to me how can I get correctly the whole results set?
Am I forced to query a local DBpedia dump in order to correctly get the results?

Thank you a lot in advance.

EDIT:
I've created a new query using the useful suggestion @Joshua Taylor:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?movie (str(?movie_year) as ?year) (str(?movie_title) as ?title)  WHERE {
?movie rdf:type dbpedia-owl:Film.
movie rdfs:label ?movie_title.
FILTER langMatches(lang(?movie_title), \"EN\") .
optional { ?movie dbpprop:released   ?rel_year }
optional{?movie dbpedia-owl:releaseDate ?owl_year}
 optional {?movie dcterms:subject ?sub.
 ?sub rdfs:label ?movie_year_sub
 filter regex(?movie_year_sub, ".*[0-9]{4}.*", "i") }
 BIND(COALESCE(?owl_year, ?rel_year, ?movie_year_sub) AS ?movie_year)
 } group by ?movie limit 2000 offset $specific_offset
```

Using the group by specification, the virtuoso endpoint let me to get the correct results set which doesn't have duplicates row.
Instead when I try to run the query using apache Jena, I'm not able to execute it because I receive the following error:

```
com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryParseException: Non-group key variable in SELECT: ?movie_year in expression str(?movie_year)
```

Comment: In this case, the number is the same, but to count distinct films, you should use `select (count(distinct ?film) as ?nFilms) where { … }`.  Note the placement of `distinct`;  i.e., `select (count(distinct …`, not `select distinct (count(…`.

Comment: "As you can see in the java code…"  I don't see any Java code in the question.  Please add it to the question.

Comment: While it's surprising that you'd get such a round number (76000), you'll "miss" any films that don't have one or more of the specified properties you're asking about, or if the values don't match the filter.  Sure, there are 77794 films, but are there that many with a specific title, with English titles,and that have years matching the regex you've got?

Comment: Thank you Joshua. You're perfectly right.
How can I do in order to solve this problem? I'm just thinking about a simple query that makes the union of the films which matches the query that I've created or the one that has only the rdf:type equal to dbpedia-owl:Film as a constraint. Can you suggest to me a good method in order to complete my task?

Comment: What exactly is is that you want?  A year and a title for each movie?

Comment: Year, title and the dbpedia uri of the film.

Comment: wow, looking at some of the dbpedia data, I see why you were doing a regex match on the category.  Some of them really don't have much date information, do they?

Comment: Exactly. 
At the moment my task is to get has much films as I can with all the required information that I've written before. 
Thank you a lot for your patience. I really appreciate it :)

Comment: Well, I added a query to my answer that should help you get toward extracting *enough* information to get what you want, although it's not quite everything.  You might also get to the point of running a regular expression on the abstracts of things to extract a year from them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are more films than those that satisfy your original query, and your query doesn't necessarily count each movie just once.  There's big difference between `select distinct (count(?var) as ?nVar) …` and `select (count(distinct ?var) as ?nVar) …`.  The first only shows you distinct counts, whereas the second shows you the number of distinct bindings.

You can get more than one result row for each movie.  In this part of your query:

```
?movie rdf:type dbpedia-owl:Film.
?movie dcterms:subject ?cat .
?cat rdfs:label ?movie_year .
FILTER regex(?movie_year, "^[0-9]{4} ", "i")
```

you'll get a result row for a each matching label of each category to which the movie belongs.  E.g, if some film is in categories *1984's Worst Movies* and *2010 Film Remakes*, you'll get two result rows.

There are also legitimate films that you won't be counting, because some films might not have an English movie title or a category that begins with a year.

I'm not sure whether you'll be able to get entirely satisfactory results, since it appears that DBpedia just doesn't reliably have the data that you want.  That said, try a query like this to get started.  It will get *all* films, and and will (hopefully) pull out enough information to get dates in many cases.  Some the dbpprop:released values are very strange though, and I don't know how useful they'll be to you.

```
select * where { 
  ?film a dbpedia-owl:Film 
  optional { ?film dbpprop:released        ?released    }
  optional { ?film dbpedia-owl:releaseDate ?releaseDate }
  optional { ?film dcterms:subject [ rdfs:label ?catLabel ]
             filter( regex( ?catLabel, "^[0-9]{4}.*films", "i" ) )
           }
}
order by ?film 
limit 100
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=select%20%2a%20where%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20?film%20a%20dbpedia-owl%3aFilm%20%0D%0A%20%20optional%20%7B%20?film%20dbpprop%3areleased%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20?released%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20optional%20%7B%20?film%20dbpedia-owl%3areleaseDate%20?releaseDate%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20optional%20%7B%20?film%20dcterms%3asubject%20%5B%20rdfs%3alabel%20?catLabel%20%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20filter%28%20regex%28%20?catLabel,%20%22%5E%5B0-9%5D%7B4%7D.%2afilms%22,%20%22i%22%20%29%20%29%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aorder%20by%20?film%20%0D%0Alimit%20100&format=text/html&timeout=30000&debug=on)

### Update after new query

The query that you've posted that doesn't work with Jena (because it's not legal SPARQL, even though Virtuoso accepts it) can be fixed in a few different ways, depending on what exactly you want.  The simplest, most direct way, is simply not to group on anything.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?movie (str(?movie_year) as ?year) (str(?movie_title) as ?title)
WHERE {
  ?movie rdf:type dbpedia-owl:Film.
  ?movie rdfs:label ?movie_title.
  FILTER langMatches(lang(?movie_title), 'en')
  optional { ?movie dbpprop:released   ?rel_year }
  optional { ?movie dbpedia-owl:releaseDate ?owl_year}
  optional { ?movie dcterms:subject ?sub.
             ?sub rdfs:label ?movie_year_sub
             filter regex(?movie_year_sub, ".*[0-9]{4}.*", "i")
           }
  BIND(COALESCE(?owl_year, ?rel_year, ?movie_year_sub) AS ?movie_year)
}
limit 2000
```

If you do that, though, you'll get multiple results when you have multiple English movie titles, release years, etc.  If you want to avoid that, then you want to `group by ?movie`.  Jena's right to reject things like

```
select ?movie (str(?movie_title) as ?title) where { 
  ?movie :hasTitle ?movie_title
}
group by ?movie
```

because `str(?movie_title)` doesn't make sense.  For each `?movie`, you've actually a set of `?movie_title`s.  You need to get a representative title from that set.  Now, it doesn't actually look like any movie has more than one English title.  You can check with a query like:

```
SELECT ?movie (count(?mTitle) as ?nTitles)
WHERE {
  ?movie a dbpedia-owl:Film ;
         rdfs:label ?mTitle .
  filter langMatches(lang(?mTitle),'en')
}
group by ?movie
having count(?mTitle) > 1
```

Given that, it means that you can safely `group by ?movie ?movie_title` which will let you use `?movie_title` in the projection variable list.  But what to do about the release date?  You could still end up with more than one of those, in principle.  The data does give you more than one, in fact, as you can see with this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?movie (group_concat(?movie_year;separator=';') as ?years)
WHERE {
  ?movie rdf:type dbpedia-owl:Film.
  ?movie rdfs:label ?movie_title.
  FILTER langMatches(lang(?movie_title), 'en')
  optional { ?movie dbpprop:released   ?rel_year }
  optional { ?movie dbpedia-owl:releaseDate ?owl_year}
  optional { ?movie dcterms:subject ?sub.
             ?sub rdfs:label ?movie_year_sub
             filter regex(?movie_year_sub, ".*[0-9]{4}.*", "i")
           }
  BIND(COALESCE(?owl_year, ?rel_year, ?movie_year_sub) AS ?movie_year)
}
group by ?movie ?movie_title 
having count(?movie_year) > 1
limit 2000
```

This means that you'll need to get a value based on that set.  SPARQL gives you a few functions to do that (e.g., `max`, `min`, `sum`).  In this case, I don't know if there's an easy way to pick the "best" representative, so you might just want to `sample` from it, giving you a query like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?movie (str(sample(?movie_year)) as ?year) ?movie_title
WHERE {
  ?movie rdf:type dbpedia-owl:Film.
  ?movie rdfs:label ?movie_title.
  FILTER langMatches(lang(?movie_title), 'en')
  optional { ?movie dbpprop:released   ?rel_year }
  optional { ?movie dbpedia-owl:releaseDate ?owl_year}
  optional { ?movie dcterms:subject ?sub.
             ?sub rdfs:label ?movie_year_sub
             filter regex(?movie_year_sub, ".*[0-9]{4}.*", "i")
           }
  BIND(COALESCE(?owl_year, ?rel_year, ?movie_year_sub) AS ?movie_year)
}
group by ?movie ?movie_title 
limit 2000
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=%20%20%20%20SELECT%20DISTINCT%20?movie%20%28str%28sample%28?movie_year%29%29%20as%20?year%29%20?movie_title%0D%0A%20%20%20%20WHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20?movie%20rdf%3atype%20dbpedia-owl%3aFilm.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20?movie%20rdfs%3alabel%20?movie_title.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20FILTER%20langMatches%28lang%28?movie_title%29,%20%27en%27%29%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20optional%20%7B%20?movie%20dbpprop%3areleased%20%20%20?rel_year%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20optional%20%7B%20?movie%20dbpedia-owl%3areleaseDate%20?owl_year%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20optional%20%7B%20?movie%20dcterms%3asubject%20?sub.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20?sub%20rdfs%3alabel%20?movie_year_sub%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20filter%20regex%28?movie_year_sub,%20%22.%2a%5B0-9%5D%7B4%7D.%2a%22,%20%22i%22%29%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20BIND%28COALESCE%28?owl_year,%20?rel_year,%20?movie_year_sub%29%20AS%20?movie_year%29%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20group%20by%20?movie%20?movie_title%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20limit%202000%0D%0A%0D%0A&format=text/html&timeout=30000&debug=on)

This is legal SPARQL, confirmed by the [sparql.org validator](http://sparql.org/validate/query) (once you provide some prefix definitions), so Jena should be fine with it, and Virtuoso (in this case, the DBpedia endpoint) accepts it, too.

Comment: Apparently the releaseDate information is in milliseconds. I think that represents the amount of time between the film's release date and January 1, 1970. Could it be?

Comment: @AlessandroSuglia Don't expect the data to be too clean.  It's not. Did you look at the results of the query I posted?  Compare some of the values where there's both a released and a releaseDate value.  E.g., `http://dbpedia.org/resource/$9.99` that's `released 4`, but `releaseDate 2008-09-03+02:00`, and `http://dbpedia.org/resource/%22Weird_Al%22_Yankovic:_The_Ultimate_Collection` with `released 1993` (but no `releaseDate`).  The values aren't normalized.  Those are dbpedia infobox properties (dbpprop).  The ontology (dbpedia-owl) properties are much cleaner.

Comment: I've noticed it. But is there a way in order to do a "clean union" of multiple results which are able to manage some possible cases?
Something like this: http://pastie.org/9248061

Comment: well, the dbpedia-owl values should always be better, so you can use `coalesce` to take them if they're available, and the dbpprop otherwise.  Take a look at this question on answers.semanticweb.com [*Preference patterns for SPARQL (1.1)*](http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/20682/preference-patterns-for-sparql-11).  I have to run for the moment, but hopefully that will give you some ideas.

Comment: I've finally found the query that return exactly what I need but apache Jena doesn't grant to me to use the group by option on a single variable :/
Any ideas?

Comment: Post your query in the question. Virtuoso (the endpoint that powers DBpedia) accepts a lot of things that aren't actually legal SPARQL queries (check with sparql.org's validator).  Even so, most of the illegal queries that it accepts have a legal form that Jena will parse and that Virtuoso will accept.

Comment: I've updated my question following your suggestions.

Comment: @AlessandroSuglia Yeah, if you group by ?movie, then you'll need to use something like `sample` in the `select`, e.g., `select (str(sample(?movie_year)) as ?year) …`, or just `group by` with more than one variable, e.g., `group by ?movie ?movie_year limit …`.

Comment: @AlessandroSuglia If you get your query fixed up so that it's legal, please be sure to post it as an answer and mark it as accepted.  It will be valuable to others who find this question.

Comment: At the moment, it's not legal for the apache jena library. Any ideas?

Comment: If you take my advice and paste the query (not the code that generates it;  we want something that we can copy and paste, please) into the question, then we can probably figure out what needs to change to make it legal.  As I said in my earlier comment, "most of the illegal queries that it accepts have a legal form that Jena will parse and that Virtuoso will accept.", and in a comment after that I pointed out one possible way to fix the query with `sample`.

Comment: @AlessandroSuglia I've updated my answer.  I think you'll be all set now. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55013/discussion-between-alessandro-suglia-and-joshua-taylor).

Comment: @AlessandroSuglia If you've got `select distinct` there, you shouldn't be getting duplicate results.  What duplicate results do you get?

Comment: In a single query I don't have duplicates. But If I merge the results which come from different queries, I got the same resource URI with different genre.

Comment: There's no genre in you query, so I don't have any idea what results you'd be talking about.  Perhaps rather than grouping by ?genre, you should be sampling it, as well?